# Add css and Javascript code

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco5, umbraco-blog

The code below works fine.I'm try to add my java script and CSS to Umbraco..im doing some data migration but I'm not sure where to add cause I'm new to umbraco..I'm using Umbraco 3.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ddaccordion.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

ddaccordion.init({
    headerclass: "submenuheader", 
    contentclass: "submenu", 
    revealtype: "click", 
    mouseoverdelay: 200, 
    collapseprev: true, 
    defaultexpanded: [],
    onemustopen: false,
    animatedefault: false, 
    persiststate: true, 
    toggleclass: ["", ""],
    togglehtml: ["suffix", 
    animatespeed: "fast",
    oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ 
    },
    onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated
    { 
        //do nothing
    }
})
</script>


<style type="text/css">

.glossymenu{
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 0;
width: 170px; /*width of menu*/
border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
border-bottom-width: 0;
}

 </style>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log into the CMS yoursite.com/umbraco/ then go to the settings tab (bottom left) then expand the templates (left hand tree). In there look for the "master" template that has the  information.

Click on it, you'll see the code in the right hand panel. You can edit the code right in there, past your new code and save.

(I'm not so sure how Umbraco 3 work (more familiar with 4 or 6), but I think this will point you in the right direction.)